# Batch file/alias/powershell to activate/deactivate IE 11 proxy server

Tags: windows, batch, internet-explorer, powershell, cmd.exe

I would like to have a batchfile/cmd alias/powershell command to switch the useage of a proxy server in IE11 on and off, so basically to check/uncheck the following settings:
IE->Options->Connections->LAN->Proxyserver Checkbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the following powershell code to edit the registry keys for enabling IE proxy settings:

```
$reg = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
$settings = Get-ItemProperty -Path $reg
```

Configure the proxy server address, and enable it:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path $reg -Name ProxyServer -Value "proxy.example.org:8080"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $reg -Name ProxyEnable -Value 1
```

To disable proxy, just adjust the `ProxyEnable` value to `0`:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path $reg -Name ProxyEnable -Value 0
```

Tested on Windows 10 client.